# Is it possible to import Eclipse code templates into Netbeans?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, import, code-templates

I've recently switched to netbeans from eclipse thinking it will be enough for me to develop  php apps and some java desktop apps(crawlers).How can I import all my code editor templates into netbeans?
There seems to have a [question](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic22054.html) already but not yet answered.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. Currently, there is nothing available to convert code templates from Eclipse to Netbeans :-(